# Java/Spring ActiveMQ Continuous Listening

Tags: java, spring

I'm looking at building a very simple application that monitors an ActiveMQ queue for messages and when a message is received into the queue, process it.

For example an order processing system that listens to the queue for messages and then triggers a method/service when one is received.

How to configure applications such as this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These ones are more Spring-orientated:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-jms-activemq

http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-activemq-producer

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of googling I came up with these examples of what you want:

http://activemq.apache.org/tomcat.html

http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-embed-a-broker-inside-a-connection.html